# Based on condition Disable Field/Remove addresscomplete pca control from dynamics crm field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am using addresscomplete pcf control on a single line text field 'Address' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvzoN.png)

I want to disable addresscomplete conditionally. For e.g. if Age < 18 disable addresscomplete on field Address.

I tried disabling the field Address using javascript but it is still allowing search in the field.

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable/disable control based on some client-side logic you have to handle it in the code of your control. In order to react on client-side enabling/disabling you should bound disabled property of your component to context.mode.isControlDisable of the context of your PCF control.

Comment: Can you help me with the code ?

Comment: You can check the code here - https://dynamicsninja.blog/2019/11/25/is-your-pcf-control-read-only/